# Grid CSS container that scrolls horizontally when children use grid-column?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

### [CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ywKNVg](https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ywKNVg)

I'm trying to achieve this layout in GridCSS:

[image]

**Problems:**

I'm having trouble making the children `.elements` overflow their parent `.grid` when using `grid-column: span 4;`.

**Note:**

- Children will peak on mobile
- Grid will have scroll bars if children overflow
- Children perfectly follow the grid.

**Question:**
Is it possible to make CSS Grid Items overflow with a scroll bar when its children are aligned to the grid using `grid-column`? if so, what properties am I missing? If not, is are there any work arounds to achieve these layouts shown above, when using CSS Grid?

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
     <!-- UNCOMMENT BELOW   -->
    <!--       <div class="element">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
    <div class="copy">
       Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
    </div>
  </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 64px 48px;
  background: green;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1032px;
  background: rgba(244,244,244, .25);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;   
  grid-auto-flow: column;  
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 48px;
}


.element {
  padding:30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: papayawhip;
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to get rid of `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);`<sup>1</sup>. No need to define column template since your number of element is unknown, let the browser handle this automatically by defining the implicit grid.

You may need to define `grid-auto-columns` to set the width of each column.

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 64px 48px;
  background: green;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1032px;
  background: rgba(244, 244, 244, .25);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-gap: 48px;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(40px, 1fr);
}

.element {
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: papayawhip;
  grid-column: span 4;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://placebear.com/400/500" alt="">
        <div class="copy">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, eveniet commodi?
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Remove `grid-auto-columns: minmax(40px,1fr);` from above and you will see this for the top grid:

[image]

The red lignes are your columns with 0 width and as you can see each item is simply equal to 3 gaps. By setting the `minmax()` we will use `1fr` when there isn't overflow and only few elements (enough space for `1fr`). When will have a lot of elements and the `1fr` will get smaller you will fix the width to `40px`.

Basically each element will have a `min-width` equal to `4*40px + 3*48px` in this case. and if you remove the `1fr` and use `grid-auto-columns: 40px;` then the `min-width` will simply be the `width`.

---

<sup>1</sup>  The issue when defining the template columns is that you will told the browser that you have `12` columns with `1fr` and later you will be using more if you have more than 3 items thus the implicit grid will contain more than `12` columns and the browser may calculate their width differently from what you set.

Here is as simplified example to illustrate:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
img {
  grid-column:span 2;
  border:2px solid green;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
</div>
```

Notice how the width of the first 2 images is different from the last 2. The first ones are inside the grid you defined and the other inside the one created by the browsers.

By only setting `grid-auto-columns` you are sure that all will have the same width:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns:minmax(40px,1fr);
}
img {
  grid-column:span 2;
  border:2px solid green;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=0">
</div>
```

Comment: I marked it correct cuz I wasn't explict enough but How can I guarantee so many items per break points. Like 3 on desktop, 2 on tablet, 1 and a peek (1/4) on mobile?

Comment: I just made another question cuz I wasn't clear in this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189168/horizontal-scrolling-css-grid-with-fixed-number-of-grid-items-per-breakpoint