Multi column slider

I am trying to find an elegant solution with little JavaScript to create carousel which can have one or multiple columns. With a click on the buttons, it should scroll to the next column(s).
Idea (too much JS in my opinion):

Create a grid grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
With JavaScript find out how many columns there currently are and fill grid
Resizing: We need a ResizeObersiver to find out if the number of columns change when the user resizes the window and adjust the content. -> Ugly

I am trying to find a solution to avoid using a ResizeObserver. Ideally something where css automatically takes care of the number of columns and column widths and side scrolling without complicated JS logic. Anyone has a elegant solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55189168/8620333

CSS can do everything you require except for dealing with the next and previous buttons when they are clicked.
This snippet defines an element, view, which you give the width you want the slides to be seen in. This is centered.
Within it is an element, slider, which has all the items side by side by making them display inline-block. [There didn't seem any particular need to use grid or flex here].
The snippet has the gap between the items defined and then works out the width of each element, but of course you could do it the other way round.
The next/prev slide is moved to by altering the left value of slider.
There have to be two copies of the slides because if you want to cut down on the JS you need CSS to just be able to show the next one (which may be the first one when moving to next for example).
JS is used for the two click events, when it senses the slider is half way through it repositions it so there are always items to the right. This repositioning is not seen by the user because it takes place in just one frame (using requestAnimationFrame) and then the actual required transition takes place.
The CSS adjusts the widths to suit the viewport width, no need for JS to sense resizing.


<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  
  .view {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: var(--visibleW);
    --visibleW: 80vw;
    /* the width of slider that you want to be actually showing */
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: relative;
    --showN: 1;
    /* the number of items to show at a time, varies with viewport width */
    transition: left var(--time);
    left: calc(-1 * var(--itemI) * var(--visibleW) / var(--showN));
  }
  
  .slider>* {
    --margin: 5vw;
    /* half the gap between items */
    margin: 0 var(--margin);
    height: min(80vh, 300px);
    /* for demo, set to what you want */
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc((var(--visibleW) - (var(--showN) * 2 * var(--margin))) / var(--showN))/* the width of each item including the 'gap' */
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .slider {
      --showN: 3;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1500px) {
    .slider {
      --showN: 4;
    }
  }
  
  button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: min(24px, 5vw);
    padding: 10px;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .prev {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  
  .next {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="slider">
      <div style="background: red;"></div>
      <div style="background: green;"></div>
      <div style="background: blue;"></div>
      <div style="background: yellow;"></div>
      <div style="background: red;"></div>
      <div style="background: green;"></div>
      <div style="background: blue;"></div>
      <div style="background: yellow;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="prev"><</button>
  <button class="next">></button>
</div>
<script>
  const view = document.querySelector('.view');
  const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
  const next = document.querySelector('.next');
  const num = slider.children.length;
  const time = '1s'; //set this to the time you want the sliding to next one to take
  let itemI = 0; // this is the index of the item that is the leftmost in the view
  view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
  slider.style.setProperty('--time', time);
  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (itemI > 0) {
      itemI--;
      view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
    } else {
      itemI = num / 2;
      view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
      slider.style.transition = "left 0s";
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        itemI--;
        slider.style.transition = "left var(--time)";
        view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
      });
    }
  });
  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (itemI != (num / 2)) {
      itemI++;
      slider.style.transition = "left var(--time)";
      view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
    } else {
      itemI = 0;
      view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
      slider.style.transition = "left 0s";
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        itemI++;
        slider.style.transition = "left var(--time)";
        view.style.setProperty('--itemI', itemI);
      });
    }
  });
</script>



